# Making SAPI sing

Tags: powershell, wav, sapi

I'm working on a PowerShell script to create wav files of synthesized singing using SAPI. I've run into several problems:

1. I don't know how to make pauses.
2. I can't seem to make a sequence of speech with changes in rate, without overwriting the wav file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use [SSML](http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis/) and the [`SpeechSynthesizer.SpeakSSML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.speakssml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Then you can use the [`<break>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis/#edef_break) element to specify a pause time, and the [`<prosody>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis/#edef_prosody) element to specify changes in rate.